# Querying Child Nodes Based on a Particular Value (Swift 3, Firebase)

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to pass a phone number (Ex. 1111111111) and see if it matches any of the entries in my Firebase Database. I am having problems sorting through the database and looking up the phone number. Below is the Firebase Database's JSON code.

```
{
  "Users" : {
    "3SMHwMuA8HQm9yLoivxYoCtUccr1" : {
      "Email" : "firstname1.lastname1@gmail.com",
      "First Name" : "First Name 1",
      "Last Name" : "Last Name 1",
      "Phone Number" : "(111) 111-1111"
    },
    "NvQiGzASw2QDAMcBQLx1HNzR8ZM2" : {
      "Email" : "firstname2.lastname2@gmail.com",
      "First Name" : "First Name 2",
      "Last Name" : "First Name 2",
      "Phone Number" : "(222) 222-2222"
     },
    "RuVMfHUC8qQg8KGVJitEkzq9Tsy2" : {
      "Email" : "firstname3.lastname3@gmail.com",
      "First Name" : "First Name 3",
      "Last Name" : "Last Name 3",
      "Phone Number" : "(333) 333-3333"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code that I wrote. It is not giving the correct result.

```
phoneNumber: Int = 1111111111
ref = Database.database().reference()
let phoneNoInDatabase = ref.child("Users").queryEqual(toValue: phoneNo_pb_int)
let phoneNoInDatabaseInt = Int(phoneNoInDatabase.components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted).joined())
if phoneNoInDatabase_int == phoneNo_pb_int {
    // Success!
    print("User Found")
}
else {
    // Error!
    print("User not Found")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing an instruction for what child to filter on:

```
let phoneNoInDatabase = ref.child("Users").queryOrdered(byChild: "Phone Number").queryEqual(toValue: phoneNo_pb_int)
```

Comment: I'm afraid your solution did not work. I added your code and the behavior is still the same. Thank you for your effort.

Comment: It seems that you keep the phone number as a number in the code. In the database you store it as a string. So you'll need to convert it to a string: `queryEqual(toValue: "1111111111")`

Comment: That does not seem to be the case because it always matches one number - (333) 333-3333 when this is selected from the phone contact list. This number finds a match. Whereas the other 2 numbers don't; even though they are in the database.